# How to return a boolean with a adjustable name from a custom Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm attempting to develop a `customHook` for the `MUI breakpoints` right now.

The return value should depend what was entered, if possible.
As an illustration, if I enter Md, I want isGreaterThanMd and if I enter XS, I want isGreaterThanXs back. Unfortunately, my plan is too straightforward and doesn't work.

```
import { Breakpoint, useMediaQuery, useTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const useResponsiveKey = (key: number | Breakpoint) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isGreaterThan = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up(key));

    return {
        isGreaterThan: `isGreaterthan${key}`,
    };
};
```

Comment: You can use brackets in the key name of the return object `return { [\`isGreaterThan${key}\`]: isGreaterThan };`

Comment: Ho wo I make it uppercase :D ? The first letter

Comment: [`isGreaterThan${key.toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.toString().slice(1)}`]: isGreaterThan,

Comment: @LLai Please let me know if there is a way to offer autocompletion or an error so that new devs will know if they are using the wrong name. Because an incorrect name currently just remains undefined

Comment: I would make the argument `key` strict so you can only pass in valid values `(key: Breakpoint) => {}` Its also probably a good idea to have the function return a default value

Comment: I did that. Somebody could still choose any isGreaterThan without the key and would get an undefined. Thats kinda stupid.

Comment: Yeah a default value is a good idea